# Can a initialized File be null?

Tags: java, file, null

I have the following scenario:

```
File file = new File(path);
```

If we perform this line in Java, it is not necessary to do a try catch, because I am not interested in the correctness of the file. But can it happen, that still, `file` is `NULL`?

I think that it can't be `NULL`, but since I am unexperienced, I would like some feedback.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `new` keyword never returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go *one* level higher and talk about what initialization actually means.  You're asking if you initialize an object, if it can be `null`.

That wouldn't make much sense.  An object which is initialized will *never* be null.  If an object *cannot* be initialized, it should throw an exception at runtime.

`File` doesn't throw an exception if you give it a bogus path, but if you try to *write* that file to a bogus path or a path you don't have permission to, you'll get your exception *then*.  You only get an exception at initialization if `path` happens to be `null`.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. I know it was a dumb question, but I am now working on a code written by someone else. That person should be more experienced, and if you see that someone really tried to check a initialized file on `NULL`, you doubt your thoughts... At least I am unsure enough to react like that.